# Express js router not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my home.js code

```
    // import modules
    var express = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
    var cors = require ('cors');
    var path = require ('path');

    var app = express();
    const route= require('./routes/route');

    //port no
    const port =3000
    app.use(cors());

    app.use(bodyparser.json());
    //static files
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

    app.use('./api', route);
    //testing server
    app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('foober');
    })

    app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log('server started at port:' + port);
    });
```

And this the route.js code

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();

    router.get('/contacts', (req, res, next )=>{

    res.send('retrieve contact');
    });

    module.exports =router;
```

But whenever I run 'localhost:3000/api/contacts' i get 'Cannot GET /api/contacts' error. I am very new at this, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `'./api'` with `/api/`

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A dot in an url is there to seperate domains, if your route is mounted at `./api` you would have to visit `yourserver.com./api` which won't work as the url is invalid.